# Missing number, treated as zero within simple parbox/spacebox macro

Tags: parbox

I have a macro using parbox, spacebox, and some simpler whitespace. This generates a "Missing number, treated as zero." error for every time I use the macro. It still compiles to a PDF successfully with at least some distributions. (Overleaf succeeds; Windows MikTeX fails from *something* in the file but I'm not sure whether it's this.) But what's going on?

```
\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
    \noindent\hangafter     % Indentation
    \parbox{\spacebox}{     % Box to align text
    \textit{#1}}#2 \par}    % Entry value
(...)
\PersonalEntry{Phone}{555 555 5555}
```

Full error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
\parbox ->\protect 
                   \parbox  
\PersonalEntry ...-> \noindent \hangafter \parbox 
                                                  {\spacebox }{ \textit {#1}...
l.128     \PersonalEntry{Phone}{555 555 5555}
                                             
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error message you get.

Comment: Since you mention an error message and at the same time claim that the code "still compiles to a PDF successfully": Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: `\hangafter` is an internal TeX register, so it must be followed by a number, like `\hangafter=1`.

Comment: Why do you use `\hangafter` primitive register without following number in your macro?

Comment: Not sure how `\spacebox` is defined, but unless it is a specified length, it will generate an error, as that is what `\parbox` is looking for.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thank you, that is a helpful answer